# How do I show that my project uses ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if there are any kinds of stickers or decals that I could put on my project to show that I use ROS as a platform.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9861/how-do-i-show-that-my-project-uses-ros?/) by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6414 on 2011-05-01

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-05-01**:
+1 We want goodies! :D

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-11-25**:
+1 Hungry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you e-mail me a shipping address, I will try to send you ROS vinyl stickers next time we get a batch in.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-05-02**:
My username (kwc) at willowgarage.com .

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-05-02**:
I feel stupid to ask but... where to get your email? :) your blog is not really giving it and I can't find a kind of PM mechanism on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here at the lab we had some vinyl stickers made saying "ROS inside", you can check them out at [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/lse_roomba_toolbox/Tutorials/Assembling%20a%20Roomba), first picture.

If you want I can send you the files I used to order the stickers, though it would be cool if the guys at WillowGarage sold some ROS stickers :)

---

Originally posted by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) with karma: 591 on 2011-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Oh yes.  ROS stickers need to happen!

---

Originally posted by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) with karma: 422 on 2011-05-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1